# How to use Front Camera In android

Tags: android, camera

i need Some Help help I am Working With An app which Can take picture automatic On Activity With Main Camera But I want to use Front Camera Instead Of Main Camera 
can U Please Tell Me How To use  Front Camera

here Is My Code

```
public class TakePicture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    //a variable to store a reference to the Image View at the main.xml file
    private ImageView iv_image;
    //a variable to store a reference to the Surface View at the main.xml file
    private SurfaceView sv;

    //a bitmap to display the captured image
    private Bitmap bmp;

    //Camera variables
    //a surface holder
    private SurfaceHolder sHolder;  
    //a variable to control the camera
    private Camera mCamera;
    //the camera parameters
    private Parameters parameters;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //get the Image View at the main.xml file
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //get the Surface View at the main.xml file
        sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        //Get a surface
        sHolder = sv.getHolder();

        //add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View callbacks
        sHolder.addCallback(this);

        //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
        sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
    {
         //get camera parameters
         parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

         //set camera parameters
         mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
         mCamera.startPreview();

         //sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
         Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() 
         {
             @Override
             public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
             {
                 //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
                 bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                 //set the iv_image

                 iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                 TakePicture t=new TakePicture();
                 t.SaveBitmap(bmp);
                // SendEmail(bmp);
             }


         };

         mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw the preview.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {
        //stop the preview
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        //release the camera
        mCamera.release();
        //unbind the camera from this object
        mCamera = null;
    }
```

Comment: You can refer http://thanksandroid.com/android-custom-camera/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openFrontFacingCamera() {
        numberOfCamera = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
            camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BACK TO FRONT" ,
1000).show();
                try {
                    camera.release();
                    camera = Camera.open(camId);
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    previewing = true;
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }else if(camId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FRONT TO BACK" , 



 1000).show();
                    try {
                        camera.release();
                        camera = Camera.open(camId);
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                        camera.startPreview();
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
```

hope this function will help u

Comment: in My Code Where To Use This Function Please Tell ME

Comment: first you need to create camera object globally then in oncreate call this function

Answer (score 0):

change

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
```

to

```
mCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```